# Using iPython with remote docker container in a local project directory

Tags: python, docker, ipython

I am completely new to Docker and I followed the instructions found on this page https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/setup/:

```
docker pull bamos/openface
docker run -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 -t -i bamos/openface /bin/bash
cd /root/openface
./demos/compare.py images/examples/{lennon*,clapton*}
```

And I was able to run an example of `openface` following the example. However, normally I develop in `iPython` and would like to do so. However, I cannot `import openface` from iPython, since presumably it is not installed locally. Similarly, I do not know how to cd into my project directory, which is in `/Users/name/documents/my-project`.

What is the idiomatic way to proceed?

Comment: As an alternative. Why not `git checkout` the source code from https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface. Develop it. test it. Once happy then do the `docker build -t openface.` To be able to navigate a container's file system, you can either `docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash` or you mount the directory to the host's file system.

Comment: run `pip list`,is openface installed?

Comment: @SamuelToh I am not very experienced :( and on openface's site it says: We strongly recommend using the Docker container unless you are experienced with building Linux software from source.

Comment: @pigletfly openface is not on pip or brew.

Comment: @chibro2 I think what they meant there is the software building process. That is, if you do the `docker build` way the Dockerfile would have taken care of all the steps needed to produce the binaries and to also produce a scaled down linux version to run the software.

Comment: @SamuelToh does that mean if I `git checkout` the source as you say and build (how? is there a tutorial since I'm so unfamiliar), then I can `import openface` when I'm not inside a docker container?

Comment: Why not install ipython inside the container?

Comment: @Robert my project is not in the container though, one way to do it would be to git pull my project repo from inside the container, and then modify there. Then when I modify I git push. But this seems very convoluted, I've never developed with Docker before, is this idiomatic?

Comment: As you already have the project outside the container, you can start the container with a `volume` to map your project directory to a directory inside the container. That's idiomatic. Do `docker run -v /absolute/path/to/your/project:/a/dir/inside/container (.... rest of the docker run command...)`. Do you get it?

Comment: @chibro2 for development purpose I think you should `git checkout` the source code. Run the tests, ensure they are all passing. Then depending on your plan, make the code change through `ipython shell`. Rerun the tests, when you are all happy and then you do the `docker build`. Spin up the container from your built image and give your changes some sanity checks.

Comment: @chibro2 apologise. I missed your question. You could mount the container's file system to your host, then just include the mounted path to `PYTHONPATH`. If done correctly python should recognize the package.

Comment: @Robert could you elaborate please? I've been reading docs all morning, in particular here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume, and I am still confused.

Comment: @Robert, ok I am doing `docker run -v /Users/name/Documents/my-project:/root/my-project -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 -t -i bamos/openface /bin/bash` and it is working. If you write your comment as an answer I can check resolved.

Comment: Hi chibro2, I've stepped out for a while. I will do it shortly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommended approach is using [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume). As you already have the project outside the container, you can start the container with a volume to map your project directory to a directory inside the container. That's idiomatic.

For instance:

```
docker run -v /Users/name/Documents/my-project:/root/my-project -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 -t -i bamos/openface /bin/bash
```